# Some Empty rows are not visible in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Background:

I am reading a large CSV file that contains rows over 40K+ so it required so many modifications in data which I did without any issues because I am using pandas from the last few months.

Issue: In the CSV file it contains in-between so many empty rows which contain an only a single type of hidden character called EOL

Issues: Rows which are ignored by Panda it contain hidden character EOL:

I tried to share the sample data here but the hidden character is getting removed so I am sharing a snapshot where it shows the hidden character.

[image]

This website I used to get the above info dostring.com/show-hidden-characters

I went through pretty popular questions in this forum but nothing helped me. Suggest some other solutions

Here's, How I came to know some empty rows are not visible in DF:

- checking the empty values count

  `df.example_column.isnull().sum()`

  As a result got some count
- conversion of column datatype:

  `df.example_column = df.example_column.astype('str')`

  When I used above conversion command it marks the empty columns as 'nan'
- Again the checked the `isnull().sum()` count which is zero now
- Finally, I took the data out in CSV format but saw some empty rows, this is weird now
- Then I use the following command to see the rows at the run-time

  `df[165:175]`

It surprised me again, Row number 168 and 169 are empty when you open it in MS Office. Here in the console, I can only see one row as empty which is 169 and It is marked by Panda as 'nan' at the same time row number 168 is replaced by the data of 167.

This scenario exists in the whole sheet(CSV) and panda is just ignoring the one empty row at the runtime but in MS Office you can see those rows.
I tried to share the sample data here but the hidden character is getting removed so I am sharing a snapshot where it shows the hidden character.

FYI,

here are the settings which I am using while reading the CSV file:

```
 sep=",", skipinitialspace=False, skip_blank_lines=False, encoding='utf-8'
```

---

Comment: `dropna` should work. It does with your example data.You should say what is the dtype of the column you use in the subset, and also show `type(df.at[row_index, colname'])` for one of the rows that `dropna` does not remove.

Comment: @SergeBallesta I did what you told me here:


- I have used the particular checked the datatype at other rows it is <class 'str'>

- When I jump on the blank row it gives this datatype <class 'float'>

If it is the issue with datatype then I tried already by changing the type of the whole column into str then used dropna but that time it didn't work

Comment: That's weird. As the columns contains string its dtype (control it with `df.dtypes`) should be object. If you see a float in that row, it probably means that you have a nice and true `NaN` (or `np.nan`). That is the reason why I cannot imagine a reason for `dropna` not to remove the row. Does `df[df[colname].isna()]]` selects the rows to drop?

Comment: @SergeBallesta

Today I observed something more weird thing in pandas, I was printing the dataframe output on the console 

`DF[165:175]`

The surprising thing is rows which are empty in MS excel are 168 and 169 meanwhile printing the dataframe selected rows in the console it is showing only one row which is 169, Panda is actually ignoring the line number 168 while processing the data, On the other side when you take the output in CSV, it again gives you one extra blank row.

Comment: @SergeBallesta

At the time of reading the file, here are the setting which I am using:

`sep=",", skipinitialspace=False, skip_blank_lines=False, encoding='utf-8',`

Why is that?

Comment: @SergeBallesta I just changed the question description completely.

Comment: I am sorry, but without a [mcve], it is really hard to guess what happens.